# Lotus Notes: What will be the view selection formula to select a form which is in different database?

Tags: lotus-notes

My view is one application and a required form along with few fields are in different application.

Answer (score 3):

Point one:  A View's selection formula does not "select a form". It selects documents. These documents are (usually) created with a Form, and they (usually) contain an item called "Form" which contains the name of the Form that they were created with.  So a selection formula `SELECT Form = "Foo"` means that the view will show all documents with an item named Form that contains the value "Foo".

Point two: A View can only select documents that are in the same database that contains the View. It cannot select documents that exist in another database.

Ergo, there is no possible forumla that selects documents in another database that were created with a given Form.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you probably have some keyword documents in a different database, and you'd like to use a key in the main document to pull some matching information from the keyword database. In other words, you'd like to do a "join" in your Notes view.

You can't do this, never mind whether the documents are in the same database. This is not a relational database.

There are options, however.

- You could create a "user definable" column and automatically update the column formula in a profile document so that the formula can calculate the keyword correspondences. You would have a periodic agent look at the keyword database and construct an updated formula such as, @Select("a"; "b"; "c";...; ChoiceNo) to convert the number field ChoiceNo to the value "a" (for 1), "b" (for 2), etc. If you can write a formula to display the correct values for the *current* keywords, this is workable provided the list never gets too long.
- Domino servers are capable of accessing a DB2 relational database to construct a view index, using a feature called DB2NSF. So you can actually do a join -- but your NSF data has to be stored in DB2 as its back-end, rather than beinf stored in the NSF, for this to work. This is probably going to be more work than it's worth to you for this application.
- If it is an XPages application, you can create your own data set however you like for feeding to a repeat control.